# Cache Memory Growing very fast Cent Os -Tomcat

Tags: centos, tomcat, java, tomcat6

i am running Java application on Tomcat-6 on CentOs .

JAVA_OPTS Like this  :

```
 JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=`umask` -server -Xms256m -Xmx2536m -XX:+UseParallelGC  -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2  -XX:+UseParallelOldGC  -XX:ThreadStackSize=512 -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M"
```

but cache memory of server growing

```
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32101      16153      15948          0         20       3968
-/+ buffers/cache:      12164      19936
Swap:        16383        114      16269
```

where i am doing wrong ??

Answer (score 2):

You're doing nothing wrong.  "Cached" memory in Linux is the kernel using available RAM to cache files from disk, for speedy access( no need to go to slow disk for commonly accessed files).  This is by design, and a good thing.

Comment: Obligatory link to [linux ate my ram](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) :)

Comment: I have the same problem and it ends up with crashing my java web app. Is there something else to do than reboot the server ?

Comment: Give the server more memory.  If your application needs more than the server has available, you have very little choice.